# Горизонтальная прокрутка блока div, у которого ширина указана в процентах

Tags: html, css, table

Есть таблица (`table`) с двумя ячейками (`td`), ширина которых 20% и 80% соответственно. Таблица занимает всю площадь веб-страницы. В меньшей из ячеек находится блок `div`, полностью занимавший её площадь. У блока установлена горизонтальная прокрутка, отображающаяся в зависимости от ширины контента блока и вертикальная прокрутка, отображающаяся всегда.

Всё должно выглядеть [так](https://jsfiddle.net/9dynd3vc/9/), но выглядит [вот так](https://jsfiddle.net/9dynd3vc/11/). Проблема заключается в том, что при задании блоку `div` высоты или ширины **в процентах** всё отображается некорректно. Блок `div` должен занимать всю площадь ячейки, то есть его длина и ширины должны быть равны 100%, а если я это сделаю, то горизонтальная прокрутка не отображается. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `table-layout:fixed`

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
td.a {
  width: 20%;
}

td.a div {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

td.a div p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}

td.b {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="a">
        <div>
          <p>111</p>
          <p>22222222222222222222222222</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="b">TEXT</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```